# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable in logical operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a dataframe. each row in column `B` contains a list, which is stored in `object` data type. I want to compare each row in `B` with another list. If they are equal in value, I want to add a new column indicting `TRUE`, otherwise, `FALSE`.

```
df 

B
"1st", "2nd", "3rd"
"2nd", "1st", "4th"
"1st", "2nd", "3rd"
```

I use `iterrows()` for looping into rows:

```
for index, row in df[['B']].iterrows():
    set(row['B']) == set(['1st', '2nd', '3rd'])
```

The error shows `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`, but I don't have any numeric in the comparison, why does it happen? Also, if I `print(set(row['B']) == set(['1st', '2nd', '3rd']))`, it shows `TRUE`/`FALSE`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that there are some NaN values in "B". See if

```
len(df['B']) == len(df['B'].dropna())
```

is True.

Also instead `iterrows`, you can use list comprehension where you check if you have a list or not:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[["1st", "2nd", "3rd"], ["2nd", "1st", "4th"], ["1st", "2nd", "3rd"], np.nan]})
df['new_col'] = [set(x)==set(['1st', '2nd', '3rd']) if isinstance(x, list) else False for x in df['B']]
```

Output:

```
  new_col
0   True
1  False
2   True
3  False
```